# How to do lighthouse test on a protected URL

Tags: javascript, cypress, lighthouse

I'm working on a project and need to do end-to-end testing using cypress. I need to do a lighthouse test on that project and get the performance and accessibility scores.
Currently, I'm doing lighthouse tests using the cypress-audit package. but the problem is,
we getting very low values for the performance score when compared to the chrome devtool lighthouse plugin. this happened only for the performance, the score of the accessibility got the same value for both ways. as an example for one page I got a performance score of 22 from devtools but running this method in cypress I got 2 as the performance score.

```
export function lighthouseAudit(scenarioId) {
    Cypress.config('taskTimeout', Cypress.env('lighthousePreloadingTaskTimeout'));
    cy.log("scenarioId", scenarioId);
    cy.task("getExcelData", Cypress.env("lighthouseBaseValueFilePath")).then(data => {
        const baseValueData = data.find(record => {
            return record.Id == scenarioId;
        });

        const lighthouseMetrics = {
            performance: baseValueData.performance,
            accessibility: baseValueData.accessibility,
        };

       
        const desktopConfig = {
            formFactor: 'desktop',
            screenEmulation: { disabled: true },
        };

        const lighthouseData = {
            lighthouseReportName : scenarioId,
            thresholds : lighthouseMetrics
        }

        cy.task('setLighthouseData', lighthouseData).then(() => {
            cy.lighthouse(lighthouseMetrics, desktopConfig);
        });
    });
}
```

is it correct or do I need to pass any other option to `desktopConfig` ?

I saw most of the developers experiencing this issue when using cypress-audit. then I tried a new approach. I installed the lighthouse package globally and use this method to do the lighthouse test.

```
cy.exec(`lighthouse ${url} --chrome-flags="--headless" --preset=desktop  --emulatedUserAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" --output="json" `).then(({ stdout }) => {
    const { categories } = JSON.parse(stdout);
    var res =  Object.keys(categories).reduce((acc, key) => {
      return {
        ...acc,
        [key]: categories[key].score
      }
    }, {})

    cy.log(res)

  });
```

seems like this will give a fire score for the performance than cypress-audit.
but the issue is we can't do lighthouse tests on a protected URL using this.
because when we run the cypress it opens a new chrome instance in which we can log in to our site and then we can go to protected URLs. but when this method runs it will open a new chrome instance that does not have any previously saved cookies or session ids, because of that we can't access the protected URLs

need help finding a better solution to get the correct performance and accessibility score from the lighthouse test. and it should be able to do a lighthouse test on protected URLs aswell

Comment: Are you testing a built project in the browser vs a dev-mode project in cypress?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question. but the site has already been deployed. we have an instance for automation. I am not working on the production instance.